# XCode iPad split view controller with detail views containing several form controls

Tags: xcode, forms, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Fairly new to Mac and XCode 3.2.6 and iPad.  I have a fairly simple business data model to implement on the iPad, but can't seem to find the combination of views and controllers to use.

It's a simple data collection program, but there are too many data fields to fit on a single screen so I've resorted to the Split View approach.

I've got eight rows of table data on the left; RootViewController is the default UITableViewController.  I'm trying to write the program such that when any of those table rows are selected, the view on the right (Detail View) gets redrawn and populated with a bunch of different controls (labels, buttons, text fields, etc.) that correspond to the selection on the left.  Currently all the Details views are plain UIViewControllers.

For instance, the first "tab" might be titled "Personal", and I need to display fields to collect info such as Name, DOB, Height, Weight, etc.  The next one might be "Address" where I need to collect Street, City, ZIP Code, etc.  The next one might be "Employer", where I'd like to collect the employer's name, address, phone number, etc.  These are mostly static and unchanging, but there are enough fields for about 8 screens worth.

I've got all this laid out in Interface Builder, but when I run it on the iPad simulator and click the very first button on the very first view, the connected delegate isn't called.  I've put a breakpoint there and it's not being hit.

Is there some special magic to using simple UIViewControllers on the right side of a UISplitViewController, as far as letting them contain other simple Label, TextBox, and Button controls?

Also is there any special magic in that the framework built the original start-up code with a RootViewController.h/.m and DetailViewController.h/.m pair?  Am I correct in thinking that a single detail view represents the entire iPad screen to the right of the Table View, and that to add more "pages" we need to write more files and .XIBs like DetailViewController?

Final question is how to implement the data model for this app.  I noticed when the project was first auto-created, there weren't any source files for the model.  (Maybe most of the predefined app types don't auto-generate anything for the model, but I understand that's a big part of model-view-controller paradigm.)  Anyway these data fields on all the various views will eventually be part of a SQLite record that I'd like to save and load from storage.  Where would I begin to wire all that stuff in to all the auto-generated "view centric" code?

If anyone has seen a "how to write real business apps for the iPad" website along the lines of anything like this, please post the link.  I'm not trying to display jpegs of various fruits in a single (reused) view on the right side; I'm trying to display several real controls for real-world data collection for a real business app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basic things if you haven't already done them:
Have you connected the interface object the user is pressing from it's INSIDE TOUCH UP event to an IBOUTLET that then refreshes the right side?

If you have, and you've mucked about a bit (ie renaming and moving stuff around), try deleting it from the right-click event panel and then reconnecting it to the same IBOUTLET again (you don't have to delete any code).
Also, if you are counting on some event to fire that isn't firing, you should search on that (ie VIEWDIDLOAD NOT FIRING) because that can both occasionally be "broken" (ie no connection to the Files Owner) but more often one might misunderstand when that actually gets fired (ie VIEWDIDLOAD vs VIEWDIDAPPEAR vs VIEWWILLAPPEAR etc.)

Comment: Thanks... I did have everything connected properly but it still didn't work.  I ended up starting over from scratch using the MultipleDetailViews code as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

For your data model, CoreData is your friend. It provides a modell-oriented approach and easily allows to persist data.

For your navigation needs, I think a tabBarController better suits your needs.

Changing the detail view from the master view can be troublesome, especially when using a NavigationController as detail view. The best way I've found is using the NSNotificationCenter.

When using UISplitview I strongly recommend to support the iPad only when it's a business requirement - there are some changes in iOs 8 that make easier to use.